# Pattern not matching when string is at end

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to match the string which starts with '#' and ends with space or end of line. I am using the below function to find it.

```
function getStringsBetween($string, $start, $end)
{
$pattern = sprintf('/%s(.*?)%s/',preg_quote($start), preg_quote($end));
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}
```

I am using the below search

```
$y = "@!$+$+$+#+ hsjsjenshsjsjsj#hshsjsj ndjdjjdjdn #sem"
$output = getStringsBetween($y,"#"," ");
print_r($output);
```

the output looks like below.

```
Array ( [0] => + [1] => hshsjsj )
```

here it is missing #sem as it is end of the string and it doesn't match the pattern. How can i include end of the string to be space or end of line.

Comment: yes I need sem in index 2.

Answer (score 2):

Change your pattern so it can have the `$end` value, or the end of the line `$`.

```
$pattern = sprintf('/%s(.*?)%s/',preg_quote($start), '(?:' . preg_quote($end) . '|$)');
```

https://3v4l.org/1oqhc

Answer (score 0):

- `\s:` Matches words that have a space after
- `$:`  Match the word that is at the end of the line

My code:

```
$input_lines = "@!$+$+$+#+ hsjsjenshsjsjsj#hshsjsj ndjdjjdjdn #sem"; 
preg_match_all('/#(.*?)(?:\s|$)/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => +
    [1] => hshsjsj
    [2] => sem
)
```

Comment: `\s` has no relation to words. It is a white space

Comment: \s is for capture matches which have a white space after